# homework: Simplify f=Σ(8,12,13,14)+dΣ(3,7,9,10)

Tags: boolean

I was doing this question of boolean algebra, `Simplify f=Σ(8,12,13,14)+dΣ(3,7,9,10)` using karnaugh map.. can anyone please tell me what is d in this question? I know its a stupid question but i couldn't find it on google. And please tell me what this question means? i mean like straight away simplifying without the d expression is okay but what does the d expression signify in here ?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on math.stackexchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d stands for 'don't care'. Cells 3,7,8,10 do not affect the value of F.
This helps because you might be able to get a simpler expression if you ignore those cells.

Comment: :thanks for the answer ...  can we relate karnaugh maps to a practical use?

Comment: One use-case is developing simpler circuits to implement functions. You can easily find this information if you search.

Also, you should accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: if you can give some more explanation of why we use don't care conditions and any practical use of karnaugh maps? it would be great! :D